# Alternative to indexed view on text column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table I don't own or control being loaded from another system - and all the fields are `Text` - so obviously it's useless for any queries performance-wise.

I thought to solve the problem by creating an indexed view, which just converts every field to `int`, `date` or `varchar`...   But apparently you can't create an indexed view on a text field.

I know I can do a create table as select... but that's a once off, and it won't automatically update if someone does another load into the underlying table.

Is there any way I can make a live table without `text` columns from one with `text` columns?

Comment: Text is obsolete and will soon go out of support.  I would suggest copying the table (either locally or remotely) to a more useful table.

Comment: Can you make another table (which will be the one used more broadly) and just treat the existing table as a 'staging' or 'loading' table? e.g., the other system loads data into the current table, then a process takes the (new) data from there, cleans/converts it, and puts into the new table that you'll then actually use in queries etc?

Comment: yes - that's what I'm, doing - but the problem is - I don't control that underlying table - so I can't tell _them_ to do update _my_ table whenever the underlying table gets reloaded - so the danger is I'll continue happily using stale data.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you running locally? Do you have access to 2019?

Comment: Why not create a materialised view as these are automatically refreshed when the underlying data changes?

Comment: that would be great - sql server doesn't support materialized views as far as I know?  I'm on sql server 2016 - and have no power to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't own it or control it, so I guess a trigger is out of the question. I might give Change Tracking a try. You can use it to either sync changes as they come or trigger a reload of your version of the table. If you can't tolerate any delays in the sync, then this might not work for you.

If the updates come in large batches or via a complete reload only once in a while, then triggering a reload might be the way to go. Verify that there are no changes for a minute or so to insure the data is stable before reloading. A job scheduled to run every few minutes could handle the reload.

If doing a faster sync, then a job running a script using a loop and waitfor (seconds or minutes) could process new changes since the last run or loop.

There should be very little overhead for detecting the changes.